# Inserting Node into middle of Linked List, and accidentally inserting null node as well

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I'm working on a program that does not use Java's built in Linked List class; I'm building it from scratch.  I've been successful with everything except writing a method that inserts a Node into a particular position of the linked list.

I have a method that sets a particular Node as the "current" Node.  So, for example, I have a linked list that looks like this: **cats** --> **dogs** --> **make** --> **good** --> **pets**, and "current" is equal to 2; that means that the "current" Node is "dogs".

From here, let's say I want to insert a new Node at the position of "current" whose info field reads **and**.  If done correctly, the final linked list will be: **cats** --> **and** --> **dogs** --> **make** --> **good** --> **pets**; "and" will replace "dogs" at position 2.

So here's my problem: my method works to insert a new Node at position two, but something's going wrong with linking the newly created node to pre-existing nodes.  Not only am I inserting my new node into the list, but I'm also inserting a node with no information before "dogs".  As my code currently runs, the output looks like this: **cats** --> **and** --> (blank) --> **dogs** --> **make** --> **good** --> **pets**.

I'm 99.9% sure the problem lies in the (if current != null) portion of the code, I just can't figure out how to fix it.

Any thoughts on why I'm inserting a blank node in addition to the node I actually want to add?

```
public void insert () {

    System.out.println("Please enter the text you wish to insert, or type \"end\" if you are done inserting.");
    String theString;
    theString = console.nextLine();

    while (!theString.equals("end")){
        newNode = new Node ();
        newNode.info = theString;
        newNode.next = null;

        if (first == null){
            first = newNode;
            last = newNode;
        } else if (current != null){
            Node p = new Node (current.info, current.next);
            current.info = newNode.info;
            current.next = p;
        }
        else {
            last.next = newNode;
            last = newNode;
        }

        System.out.println("Please enter the text you wish to insert, or type \"end\" if you are done inserting.");
        theString = console.nextLine();
    }   
}
```

**EDIT**

The entire program is quite long, but here is the "setLine" method which sets current equal to whatever position the user wishes to insert their Node at.  It takes a parameter "int line" which is obtained via a user prompt.

```
public Node setLine(int line) {

    int index = 0;
    current = first;
    while (index < line) {
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
        index++;
    }
    return current;
}
```

Comment: This type of thing you just have to work through, step by step, generally with lots of System.out.println calls.  It's really a fairly common problem, but one you need to figure out yourself.

Comment: Note that you should be suspicious of the case where you create the second new Node -- you should only ever need one for any insert.

Comment: What is `console`, a `java.util.Scanner`?

Comment: Please post the rest of your code.

Comment: Yes, it would help if we had a clue as to how "current" ever gets set.

Comment: And note that if current is ever == last, last won't get updated.

Comment: Instead of guessing / verifying output, why not set up a JunitTestSuite? This will allow you to programmatically verify things and do test driven development / regression testing. This is very simple if you're using eclipse.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I had a feeling the extra constructor was the problem, but I figured you needed a way to store the value of the Node that is before the position at which you need to insert, since you're going to have to set that Node's link to the Node you're inserting.  This is a singly linked list, not a doubly linked one, so there is no reference to the previous Node.  Is there a way to temporarily store the previous Node without creating another unnecessary Node?

Comment: @DanielFischer: yes, console is a java.util.Scanner.

Comment: @JayneCobb's_HatDesigner You can implement your singly linked list with a pointer to previous instead of null, check my answer.

Comment: Your node is only two values.  You can store those values in ordinary locals -- no need to create the extra node for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that inserts the node properly. This should be a good starting point, good luck(you can read more here: http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Singly-linked_list/Insertion).

```
public class SinglyLinkedList {

      public void addLast(SinglyLinkedListNode newNode) {    
            if (newNode == null)    
                  return;    
            else {    
                  newNode.next = null;    
                  if (head == null) {    
                        head = newNode;    
                        tail = newNode;    
                  } else {    
                        tail.next = newNode;    
                        tail = newNode;    
                  }    
            }    
      }

      public void addFirst(SinglyLinkedListNode newNode) {    
            if (newNode == null)    
                  return;    
            else {    
                  if (head == null) {    
                        newNode.next = null;    
                        head = newNode;    
                        tail = newNode;    
                  } else {    
                        newNode.next = head;    
                        head = newNode;    
                  }    
            }    
      }

      public void insertAfter(SinglyLinkedListNode previous,    
                  SinglyLinkedListNode newNode) {    
            if (newNode == null)    
                  return;    
            else {    
                  if (previous == null)    
                        addFirst(newNode);    
                  else if (previous == tail)   
                        addLast(newNode);    
                  else {    
                        SinglyLinkedListNode next = previous.next;    
                        previous.next = newNode;    
                        newNode.next = next;    
                  }    
            }    
      }    
}
```

Comment: Why would `newNode` ever be null? And why wouldn't you throw an NPE instead of just ignoring it?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following method which inserts node in the middle, based on the index.

```
public boolean insertInMiddle(int index, int data){

    boolean isInserted = false;

    Node node = new Node(data);
    Node temp = head;
    int i=0;
    if(index >= 0 && index <= size()){
        isInserted = true;
        if(index == 0){
            if(head !=null){
                node.nextNode = head;
                head.prevNode = node;
                head = node;
            }else{
                head = node;
                tail=node;
            }
        }else{
            while(i<index){
                temp = temp.nextNode;
                i++;
            }               
            if(temp == null){
                node.nextNode = temp;
                node.prevNode = tail;
                node.prevNode.nextNode = node;
                tail=node;
            }else{
                node.nextNode = temp;
                node.prevNode = temp.prevNode;
                temp.prevNode = node;
                node.prevNode.nextNode = node;
            }
        }
    }       
    return isInserted;
}

//Method to get the size
public int size(){
    int size = 0;

    Node node = head;
    if(node !=null){
        while (node !=null){
            size++;
            node = node.nextNode;
        }
    }

    return size;
}
```

Comment: Not what was asked for.